# samsung s4 not responding to factory reset

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Good day

My samsung s4 just died and wount go on or charge 
I have tried the sound up and donw button with the power button with home screen button with no luck

Can any one PLEASE give me advice how to fix my phone

Comment: Do you not even get the battery charging animation when you press the power button? What has factory reset got to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

If your device's battery doesn't have any charge or power, you can not reset it.
Change your charger, or the battery, and try to see if your device is charging.